# Python Subprocess 7-Zip: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, 7zip

I have the following program to 7-Zip a directory of files via python subprocess:

```
import subprocess
import os

appPath = r'C:\\Users\Person\Desktop\7-Zip'
zApp = r'7z.exe'
zAction = r'a'
zipFileName = r'C:\\Users\Person\Desktop\test.zip'
zPass = r'password'
zAnswer = '-y'
zDir = r'C:\\Users\Person\Desktop\test'
progDir = os.path.join(appPath, zApp)

cmd = [zApp, zAction, zipFileName, zPass, zAnswer, zDir]

subprocess.Popen(cmd, executable=progDir, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, I keep running into the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am using Python 3.6 on a windows machine.

Comment: Try using the full path to the 7zip executable. Then ensure that the PATH for the process is set accordingly.

Comment: Also it should be noted that python's own standard library supports zip files as well as lzma/7z files. On the other hand, if I just wanted to call 7z as above, perhaps batch file or PS script would be more "native" way of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume it is because you don't have `C:\\Users\Person\Desktop\7-Zip` in the PATH environment variable for either the current user or the machine.

In your example you already seem to be aware of this...

Change:

```
cmd = [zApp, zAction, zipFileName, zPass, zAnswer, zDir]
```

To:

```
cmd = [progDir, zAction, zipFileName, zPass, zAnswer, zDir]
```

Or else edit the PATH environment variable for the user or machine and put the path to the 7zip executable on it so that it can be called via simply `7z`